# JQuery $.ajax and xml

Tags: xml, jquery

I have this code:

```
var xml = $.ajax({url: "aardvark-ajax.php?rand="+Math.random(),async: false, dataType:'xml'});
alert(xml);
    jQuery('image', xml).each(function(i) 
    {

        alert(jQuery(this).text());
    });
```

However, the each loop isn't working, so I'm guessing my $.ajax query is wrong.

This is the code in aardvark-ajax.php:

```
$arrImages = array(1,2,3,4);

header('Content-Type: text/xml');

    echo '<data>';

    echo '<total>' . $intTotal . '</total>';

    foreach ($arrImages as $strImage) 
    {
        echo '  <image>' . $strImage . '</image>';
    }




    echo '</data>';
```

Thge first alert(xml) outputs [object XMLHttpRequest].

Any ideas?

Comment: Dear TheBounder, please post us your plain XML response so we could resolve a possible solution for your issue on this matter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
    jQuery('image', xml.responseText).each(function(i){
        alert(jQuery(this).text());
    });
```

Comment: yeah, use the `error` and `success` callbacks from `$.ajax`, put some alerts in them so you know if the call is working or not

Answer (score 2):

you need to access the content of the XMLHttpRequest, which is easier done in the success handler of your ajax request. Something like this might work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "aardvark-ajax.php?rand="+Math.random(),
    async: false, 
    dataType:'xml'
    success:function(result) {
        jQuery('image', result).each(function(i) 
        {
            alert(jQuery(this).text());
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: and as amosrivera says, adding an error handler will help you ensure nothing is going wrong before you receive the response